# Reading files from a windows shared directory in parallel

Tags: java, windows, file, process, parallel-processing

I have a server that reads a list of text files from a windows shared directory and save it contents to the db before its starts to accepts user messages. This server will be running in multiple machines at one time.

I see that when I run the server in multiple machines, the server that starts processing the files, first processes all the files and the others keep waiting to get access to the files in that directory.

My code does this - (cannot post code due to security policy)

1. Get a list all files in the shared directory.
2. Sort them by modified date (its saving time series data)
3. While(true) till more files exist in directory
4. Get the first file in the list, and move it to InProgess folder and read
5. Save contents to database.
6. Move file to Archive directory.
7. Process the next file.

I see that when I run the same program in 2 different machines, one of them get holds of the files first and loads them all. The other one keeps waiting to get a handle on the files and if it does find a handle, they have already been processed. So it moves on.

My aim is to have the process when run in both or multiple machines to process all the file in parallel and finish faster. For now I am testing with 500 files on disk, but I can have more files on disk at any given time.

PseudoCode -

```
if(files exist on disk){
    LOGGER.info("Files exist on disk. Lets process them up first....");
    while (true) {
        File dir = new File(directory);
        List<File> fileList = new LinkedList<File>(Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles((FileFilter)FileFileFilter.FILE)));
        LOGGER.info("No of files in this process: "+ sortedFileList.size());
        if (fileList.size() > 0) {
            Collections.sort(fileList, new Server().new FileComparator());
            File file = fileList.get(0);

            //If I cannot rename the file in the same directory, the file maybe open and I move to the next file       
            if(!file.renameTo(file.getAbsoluteFile())) {
                LOGGER.info("Read next file...");
                continue;
            }
            LOGGER.info("Get file handle...");
            if (file.exists()) {
                File inprogressFile = new File(dataDirName + FileBackupOnDisk.INPROGRESS + fileName);
                saveToDB(inprogressFile);
                if (savedToDB) 
                    if(inprogressFile.renameTo(new File(dataDirName+ARCHIVE+fileName)))
                    LOGGER.info("Moved file to archive - " + fileName);
                else        
                    LOGGER.error("Move file " + fileName + " to failed directory!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's my file comparator code. This cannot be opening files -

```
final Map<File, Long> staticLastModifiedTimes = new HashMap<File,Long>();
    for(final File f : sortedFileList) {                                       
        staticLastModifiedTimes.put(f, f.lastModified());
    }

    Collections.sort(sortedFileList, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final File f1, final File f2)  {
            return           
    staticLastModifiedTimes.get(f1).compareTo(staticLastModifiedTimes.get(f2));
    }
});
```

How do I make sure that both my servers/multiple servers running on different machines are able to access the shared directly in parallel. Right now it looks like the 2nd process find that files exist in the dir but hang at one point waiting to get a file handle.

Let me know if anyone has done this before and how?

Comment: The problem is that when the code can't open a file, it keeps trying until it can, which of course doesn't happen until the file has already been processed.  The code needs to skip any files that it can't open, until it finds one that it can.

Comment: It does not go beyond the sorting point in the process that started 2nd. Even if I comment the line `code` Collections.sort(fileList, new Server().new FileComparator());`code`, it never executes the lines after that. I can put in the part to `code`continue;`code` if file.exists() is not true, but it never crosses that point.

Comment: I would guess that you're opening the files in `FileComparator` ?  At any rate, there must be a bug in your logic somewhere.  Windows does not prevent multiple machines from reading files from the same directory at the same time.  If you can determine the point in your code where it is waiting for a file handle that might help, since it shouldn't be trying to open a file at all at that point.  (Perhaps whatever Java API you are using to retrieve the modification dates opens the file?)

Comment: ... I suppose the Java runtime *could* be opening the files when you call File.listFiles() but that would be a fairly major design fault, seems unlikely to have gone unnoticed.

Comment: Thats my file comparator code. This cannot be opening files -
`code`
protected class FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    public int compare(File x, File y) {
        try {
     return new Long(x.lastModified()).compareTo(new Long(y.lastModified()));
             } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
     }
 return 0;
      }
}
`code`

Comment: I added some more logging statements in my code  and it stops at this point -

No of files in this process: 531

Its finds it difficult to get the next file handle. However, I added this after I get the file handle - 
`code`
if(!file.renameTo(file.getAbsoluteFile())) {
     LOGGER.info("CONTINUE...");
     continue;
}
`code` 

I added this to move to see if file is open, and if not I move on to next file. It does move on but the file mostly gets processed and the one of the servers just doesn't get handle to any file.

Comment: File.lastModified() might open the file.  It depends on how Sun wrote the implementation - it's not the best way to do it, but it's the most straightforward.  So if the code *is* stopping during the sort, that might be the reason.  (The easiest way to check would be to remove the sort and see whether that changes anything.)  If that's not it, I don't think we have enough information to help - sorry.

Comment: Yepp I did remove it. I had a doubt that was the bottleneck. I changed it to <look at my update above> to compare files by building up a static lookup table of last modified values to use in the comparator for each file. However, I dont see any change in the behavior.

Comment: I did comment out the sort also to see if it works.. Did not work :(
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my solution above works perfectly fine!!!!
Its just that running one instance from my eclipse with another from a m/c  in the network was causing this latency issues. 
If I run the program with 2 machines in the same network it works fine. Just that my computer was slower. Both the instances read the files when they get are able to get handle on it. 
Thank you all for your help.